# Binary division in C

Tags: c, binary, division

```
#include "stdio.h"

int bdiv( int dividend , int divisor )
{
  int remainder = dividend ;
  int quotient  = 0 ;

  int i ;
  for( i = 0 ; i < 17 ; i++ )
    {
      remainder = remainder - divisor ;
      if( (remainder & 0x8000)  )
        {
          remainder = remainder + divisor ;
          quotient  = quotient << 1 ;
        }
      else
        quotient = ( quotient << 1 ) | 0x1 ;

      divisor = divisor >> 1 ;
    }
  return quotient ;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 7 ;
  int b = 2 ;

  printf( "%d\n" , bdiv(a,b) ) ;

}
```

Pseudo-Code of the algorithm I tried to implement :

```
START
Remainder = Dividend ;
Quotient = 0 ;
1.Subtract Divisor register from remainder and place result in remainder . 
2. Test Remainder 
2a . If remainder >= 0 shift quotient to right setting rightmost bit to 1
2b. If remainder < 0 , restore the original value of the remainder register . Also shift the quotient register to the left setting the new least significant bit to 0 .
3. Shift the divisor right 1 bit .
4. is it the 33rd repetition ( for 32 bit division ) ? No : GOTO 1 
   Yes : STOP
```

I wrote this program for binary division in C for 16 bit division and it's not working . Can anyone suggest me what's not working ? 
It is giving output as `131071` for a division of 7 by 2 .

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong (or what debugging you've done so far), so no.

Comment: Explain the reason behind `remainder & 0x8000`?

Comment: Can you guys just wait a second I am posting the algorithm which I tried to implement , why is the community so dismal , downvoting everything

Comment: Because there *so many* bad questions nowadays, and most of us have lost patience...

Comment: I understand that part of it , but if someone is newly learning programming there ought to be doubts which may be silly . But the community doesn't even give a chance !

Comment: Over time, there will be fewer 'great' questions; kind of liking find the next prime number...

Comment: @AbKDs: "Bad" does not mean "beginner".  Your question (originally) didn't even say what was wrong, and it still doesn't show what debugging you've done so far.

Comment: Beginners don't even know they have bad questions or that they aren't phrasing them well -- because they are, um, beginners.  I try to give new people some initial leeway.

Comment: Hint:  Don't gripe -- that only encourages more downvotes and discourages folks from actually helping.  Simply ask what additional info is needed ***and then provide it***.

Comment: You are going through the loop `i = 0 ; i < 17`  17 times, you should be going through it 16 times-the size of the dividend in bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second shift needs to be:

```
quotient = (( quotient >> 1 ) | 0x1) ;
```

Also, why not:

```
if (remainder < 0 )
```

???

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"


int bdiv( int dividend , unsigned divisor )
{
    divisor<<=16;
    int i = 17 ;
    do { 
        dividend -= divisor ;
        if (dividend < 0) dividend += divisor ;
        else dividend++;
        i--;
        if (i) dividend<<=1;
        // printf( "%d, %d\n" , dividend, divisor ) ;
    } while (i);
  return dividend ;
}

int main()
{
    int a []= {631, 76, 760, 7600, 76000, 450333, 450333, 450333, 450333};
    int b []= {7, 75, 750, 7500, 75000, 77, 777, 7777, 77777} ;
    union doubleint {
    struct {
        short int quotient;
        short unsigned remainder;
    }part;
    int value;
    } c;
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        c.value = bdiv(a [i],b [i]);
        printf( "%d / %d = %d + %d / %d\n" , a[i], b[i], c.part.quotient, c.part.remainder, b[i] ) ;
    }
/*
unsigned c = bdiv (a,b);
printf ("%d, %d\n", c&0xffff, (c>>16)&0xffff);
*/
}

/*
631 / 7 = 90 + 1 / 7                    Correct
76 / 75 = 1 + 1 / 75                    Correct
760 / 750 = 1 + 10 / 750                Correct
7600 / 7500 = 1 + 100 / 7500            Correct
76000 / 75000 = 8 + 288 / 75000         WRONG: 75000 doesn't fit in 2 bytes
450333 / 77 = 5848 + 37 / 77            Correct: dividend does not have to fit in 2 bytes
450333 / 777 = 579 + 450 / 777          Correct
450333 / 7777 = 57 + 7044 / 7777        Correct
450333 / 77777 = 36 + 9657 / 77777      WRONG: 77777 does not fit in 2 bytes
*/
```

Comment: Please add details and explanations to your answer. Code-only answers are largely unhelpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).